# How to convert a number into hours in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

1950 minutes is 32.5 hours. How do I calculate this using a formula in Google Sheets?

I am logging the number of minutes that I take on completing tasks and need a way of converting these numbers into the number of hours in Google Spreadsheets.

I have a column that contains rows of minutes, 1 row per task. This sum total of this column then needs to be added together, then converted into hours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Add up all the values using the function **`=SUM(number1,number2,number3,number4,...)`**.
   Example: `=SUM(A1:A200)` adds up all the numbers from A1, A2, A3 ... until A200.
2. Divide the total number of hours (it's located in the field with the =SUM function) by 60 (60 minutes in 1 hour, of course) with **`=DIVIDE(number1,number2)`**
   Example: `=DIVIDE(A201,60)`. In case you put the `=SUM` function in field A201, you divide the result of that field by 60.

Answer (score 26):

Here is a function that converts minutes in hour:minutes,

```
=if( A1 = 0 ; "" ; concatenate( quotient( A1 ; 60 ) ; ":" ;MOD(A1  ; 60) ))
```

62 --> 1:2

Comment: Do you know how to add leading zero to habe e.g. 1:02?

Comment: Use the TEXT function to format the minutes. =if( A1 = 0 , "" , concatenate( quotient( A1 , 60 ) , ":" , TEXT(MOD(A1,60), "00")))

Comment: What happens when the total number of minutes (A1) is less than zero but greater than -60? Using your formula, if A1 is -30, then the formula will output 0:30, not -0:30 (I know time cannot be negative, but I'm putting together a spreadsheet to calculate the amount of available Paid-Time-Off, and need to know if that number drops below 0).  Corrected formula in next comment:

Comment: =IF(AND(A1 < 0, A1 > -60), CONCATENATE("-", QUOTIENT(A1 , 60), ":", TEXT(MOD(ABS(A1), 60), "00")), CONCATENATE(QUOTIENT(A1 , 60), ":", TEXT(MOD(ABS(A1), 60), "00")))

Comment: Sorry to be spamming this, but I realized that all negative times will not be outputted correctly via this formula.  The reason being is that (-75 mod 60) is actually 45.  Therefore -75 minutes shows up as -1:45.

Answer (score 14):

Use convert function to convert a numeric value to a different unit of measure

```
=CONVERT(A1; "mn"; "hr")
```

[Documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6055540)

Answer (score 6):

Here is a function that converts minutes in `hour:minutes`:

```
=CONVERT(A1,"mn","hr")/24
```

Where A1 is the section you want to convert

Answer (score 5):

Pierre's answer is mostly correct.  However, it does not properly output the time if the number of minutes is below 0.  If you need to handle a negative time amount, use the following formula instead:

```
=CONCATENATE(IF(AND(A1 < 0, A1 > -60), "-", ""), QUOTIENT(A1, 60), ":", TEXT(MOD(ABS(A1), 60), "00"))
```

Answer (score 3):

**I've improved it:**

---

- 123 to proper 2h 3min
- Do not show insignificant 0.

  - not show "0 mins" (number is completely divisible by 60) e.g. 120mins to 2h and NOT 2h 0min
  - not show "0h" (number is less than 60) e.g. 40min to 40min and NOT 0h 40min
- To use just replace A1 with the cell number of the cell that contains mins.

---

```
=IF (A1=0, "", CONCATENATE ( IF(QUOTIENT(A1,60)=0, "", CONCATENATE (QUOTIENT(A1,60),"h ")  ), IF(MOD(A1,60)=0,"",CONCATENATE (TEXT(MOD(A1,60),0),"min"))))
```

Comment: Works perfect for me

Answer (score 0):

I would use the functions below:

```
=TEXT(<minute>/60/24,"hh:mm")
```

(The cell containing this formula should not be formatted as time value)
And

```
=time(0,<minute>,0)
```

(The cell containing this formula should be formatted as time value, eg hh:mm)