# Converting 3 to four digit number into time with colon

Tags: google-sheets-api

I'm trying to set something up for work on Google Sheets, and I can't figure out how to get it to work. If I select hh:mm formatting, it doesn't do anything for the cells if I put in 756. It just comes up as the number.

I want to be able to have it put in so that 756 turns into 07:56 or 1355 turns into 1255 turns into 12:55.

Comment: I think that `756` can be converted to `07:56`. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `1355 turns into 1255 turns into 12:55`. Do you want to change the value of `1355` to `1255`? Can I ask you about the detail of it? And, for example, when the value of `12345` is given, what result do you want to retrieve?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that converts minutes in hour:minutes, incase you need to calculate minutes.

```
=if( A1 = 0 ; "" ; concatenate( quotient( A1 ; 60 ) ; ":" ;MOD(A1  ; 60) ))
```

`62 --> 1:2` (1 hours and 2 minutes)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23545424/15439733

So 756 Minutes = 12:36 = 12 Hours, 36 Minutes.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `=(RoundDown(A1/100)*60 + Mod(A1, 100)) / 60 / 24` to convert the format you specified (in cell `A1`) into a value that will format correctly using built in date-time formats e.g `H:mm`.

So to make `755` display as `7:55` (in another cell) put the formula above in a cell and change it's display format with menu: Format->Number->Custom Number Format to `H:mm`.

Not sure if this is what you're after though but it could be used to parse data in the format you describe for display or use in the sheet & it will work correctly with other date/time functions.

FYI the built in time format represents days as whole numbers and the fractional part is the time. The formula above just converts `756` for example to the equivalent fractional part of a day `~0.330` so it displays the equivalent time.